# Loop with load jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, for-loop, load

I make this script.

```
var arr = $('.siblings-list li').map(function() { return $(this).text() });
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $('.main').load(arr[i] + ' .section', function() {

    });
}
```

With this script. I get a array with url's and load the section of the url's in the main div. But i have a question with the load methode of jQuery. Now the script loads the section of the url's in the main div. And remove the html that's in the div. How can i change the script. That the current html in the main div not removed?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.get(arr[i]).done(function (html) {
    $(".main").append($(html).find(".section"));
});
```

However this is somewhat inefficient.  Ideally you would be able to return all of the HTML you need (and only the HTML you need) with a single request.

Answer (score 0):

When you use .load it overwrites the complete content of the selector, in this case .main is getting overwritten every time.

Try

```
$(".main").append($("<div>").load(arr[i] + ' .section', function() {
```

see how that works?